# how to manage different module version with the same anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am about to program 2 different python projects on my computer, each of them is using a different version of a specific module (PyTorch), as well as modules from the latest anaconda.
I have already installed anaconda and found out that the solution is a virtual environment, however, I don't want to install all anaconda modules for each one of them, but use the already installed anaconda for both of them. 
How do I do it?

Comment: I want to be sure I’m understanding things correctly: You’ve installed **Anaconda** twice, from https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **virtual environment** which allows you to install specific packages (with specific version) and/or specific `python` version.

From the [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html),

To create virutal environment called **myenv**

```
conda create -n myenv

# Create with specific python version
conda create -n myenv python=3.6

# Create with specific version of python and package
conda carete -n myenv python=3.5 pytorch=1.2
```

To use a virtual env, you have to **activate** it.

```
# Activating myenv
conda activate myenv
```

To **deactivate** a env, and fall back to default anaconda env,

```
# myenv
conda deactivate

conda activate base
# Anaconda default env is called base
```

To list **available** virtual env

```
conda env list
```

or

```
conda info --envs
```